# What to do when OP deletes a question right after you have posted a correct answer

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Just a moment ago I answered a basic question that involved finding the derivative of $\sin(1/x)$. A comment hinted at the chain rule, the likely best way of going about it. I took my time to spell things out and write up what I thought was a good answer. I posted this answer, and I saw that the [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26643/dotman14) obtained the end result (he posted the result in the comment thread on his question just 1 minute before I posted my answer). After posting my question, I checked out other questions on MSE and came back to the one I just answered about 3-5 minutes later to see if there were other answers or the like--the post was deleted.

**My question:** Is there a way to address people like this who delete a post after a user has taken his/her time to answer it (and provided the correct answer too)? The bothersome thing in this particular instance is that the [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/26643/dotman14) seems to be a repeat offender, having been a member of MSE for almost 3 years and yet no question, answer, etc., history at all. It seems like the person just gets his answer(s) and then deletes the question(s). I think this is pretty messed up and harmful to the MSE community--what can be done about this?

Comment: If you have enough points, you can vote to undelete. If you don't have enough points for that, you can go to the meta thread about reopening and undeleting, and post a request there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Which thread exactly? There seem to be numerous duplicates--I do not have enough points to cast an undelete vote.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks. I mean it's a rather trivial problem, but that kind of behavior is problematic IMO. Made a request. Thanks again for the link.

Comment: I'd suggest flagging for moderator attention. You have a reason to be suspicious, and the moderators have the tools to investigate (and handle) such behaviors - there's good reason to make them aware, even if you're not sure. (Although, unless you can, by some miracle, see their deleted question, I'm not sure what content of theirs you could flag, as they have none visible; you could try [the mod's office chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) or flagging an arbitrary post (of yours) - meta's not quite ideal, but it's not wholly inappropriate in the current case)

Comment: @Meelo Yes, I thought about flagging something else of the OP's but ran into that problem of *zero* history. The idea of flagging something of mine is interesting. I might have to try that.

Comment: You say they determined the result as well and signified through comment. I doubt it is anything suspicious. They may have realized it was a trivial question and thought best to delete it since they were able to answer it.

Comment: @dustin Did you see the OP's profile? Member for ~3 years and **no** history of questions of any kind. I think *that* is suspicious.

Comment: Yes, but have you read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/how-can-a-question-banned-user-fix-their-questions-if-theyre-deleted). If you delete too many or your post, you will be on a question ban. If they have deleted 100% of their (numerous) posts for 3 years, I would think that would cause the questions ban. We can delete a few without cause but if say they deleted 100 questions in 3 years, that may be noticed.

Comment: @dustin Interesting. Thanks for the link. *Maybe* it is not as suspicious as I thought it was, but it still seems odd to me, especially the barren nature of OP's profile.

Comment: Their SO account is has 23 questions. I don't know if that is any consolation, but I would think if that is their nature, they would do it there as well.

Comment: @dustin I would concur with that assessment. I'm not worried about being "consoled"--I can just imagine someone posting a much more difficult question and then someone tediously typesetting an answer only to have the post deleted. Hopefully this is just a "false alarm"

Comment: The [answer given here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8528/why-do-some-users-delete-their-questions-after-receiving-an-answer/8529#8529) says that such things should be brought to the attention of moderators.

Comment: @crash If you are talking about [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162751/how-do-i-differentiate-sin1-x), it [has been undeleted](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1162751/revisions). I wonder how the users, who voted to undelete, found the post. I thought that the posts deleted by OP are not shown in the list of deleted questions, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8540/is-there-need-to-patrol-for-deleted-questions) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277/people-who-ask-homework-questions-and-then-remove-them#comment16396_4277).

Comment: About my previous comment: Now I see that the undeletion was requested in [the long thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19757/8297). So I suppose crash had link to the question. Mystery solved.

Comment: @Martin, this user, who voted to undelete, found the post by typing the deleter's screen name into Google.

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention. We'll restore the question, unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: Maybe the profile should show number of deleted questions, comments, etc?

Comment: There is one trick: when a suspicious user posts another question, simply click on the upper left to make it one of your "favorite" questions. If deleted, you will no longer be able to see it in your favorites list, but moderators and any 10K user will be able to see it, thus quickly locating the post.

Comment: I've had a rash of these. 4 in the last week. It is quite frustrating, although in most cases I've held on to my typed answer, had the question undeleted by posting in the meta thread, and submitting my answer. However it's happened so much lately I'm worried I'm spamming the undeletion thread. Maybe I should be flagging for moderator, instead of posting in the meta thread?