# What can I do if the problem is deleted when I tried to edit my answer?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

Yesterday ($8$ hours ago) there was a problem asking to find the residue of $\exp (\csc(1/z))$ at each of its singularity. I answered that problem and then today morning, I thought to edit my answer by adding more details. Now I cannot find that problem with my answer which took me about $30$ minutes to solve. This is the first time that I experienced something like this. Is there an this that I can do regarding this?

Comment: $\exp(\text{whatever})$ never has a pole.

Comment: Related: [What to do when OP deletes a question right after you have posted a correct answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/what-to-do-when-op-deletes-a-question-right-after-you-have-posted-a-correct-answ), which suggests the use of our canonical thread for requesting reopenings, undeletions, etc.

Comment: [Related question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21866/75923).

Comment: @DanielFischer: What about $\exp(-2\ln z)$?

Comment: @celtschk On a domain where the logarithm is holomorphic except for (possibly) isolated singularities, it has no poles. Yeah, I didn't explicitly say that $\text{whatever}$ should be holomorphic except for possibly isolated singularities. I should have.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the current case, the user that had asked the question self-deleted the question. I undid this and told the user that this should not be done. (It was a new user; some believe in error that this is the intended way to use  the site or in any case do not see the problem with it.)

For the future, you can see your deleted recent answers on your profile page, 
follow the relevant link on the end of [your answers-tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers). For detailed instructions see [How to see my answer to a question that was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297922/how-to-see-my-answer-to-a-question-that-was-deleted)

In this way you can usually find out what happened. Even as a user with less than 10k points, you should be able to see your answer and the question, which typically will give an indication what happened.

In case of self-deletions for no apparent reasons or other circumstances that warrant undeletion, flag the post for moderator attention (flag, 'other') and explain that this is what happened. It typically will be undeleted, or in unusual cases we can reply why it will not be undeleted in response to the flag.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Congratulation for your new position and its really nice see you as a moderator.

Comment: Your are welcome and thank you for the congratulations!

Comment: Um.. haven't you considered that some cheaters post their homework here and then delete the question after getting an answer to try and avoid getting found out? Not saying that it's necessarily the case here, but that's my default guess when the questions look like homework. In this case the asker did provide his own attempt anyway, so it's not a bad question.

Comment: @user21820 absent evidence to the contrary I prefer to assume good faith in actions, especially when I can anyway not do much anything in the contrary case.